# 500 Internal Server Error in redirect-uri request Webflux + OAuth2.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-webflux

I'm trying to set up security for Webflux with OAuth2 to use it as a gateway. On the other hand I have my own Authorization Server. We can say that this is the structure I want to achieve:

[image: Authorization Flow]

The configuration is as follows:

WebFluxSecurityConfig.java

```
    @Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
    @EnableWebFluxSecurity
    @EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
    public class WebFluxSecurityConfig {
    
        @Bean
        public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    
            return http
                    .httpBasic().disable()
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges
                            .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/oauth2/authorization/**",
                                    "/actuator",
                                    "/actuator/**",
                                    "/auth/login",
                                    "/login/**")
                            .permitAll()
                            .anyExchange()
                                    .authenticated()
                    .oauth2Login()
                    .and()
                    .build();
    
        }
}
```

SpringGatewayApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringGatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.yml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: spring-boot-gateway
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://localhost/auth/oauth/token
      client:
        registration:
          oauth:
            client-name: oauth
            client-id: first-client
            client-secret: xxxx
            provider: adp-auth-provider
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: '{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}'
            scope: read
        provider:
          adp-auth-provider:
            authorization-uri: http://localhost/auth/oauth/authorize
            token-uri: http://localhost/auth/oauth/token
            user-info-uri: http://localhost/auth/me
            user-name-attribute: sub
```

Dependencies:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

However I am getting the following error:

[image: 500 Internal Server Error]

```
2022-01-18 12:12:15.852 ERROR 2836 --- [ctor-http-nio-6] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [477242e5-1]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/login/oauth2/code/oauth?code=nTCRNi&state=Ub8jQjbp1baxhgsxcpNULMMHoV8z42bQsp62iL2jNV8%3D"

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No provider found for class org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationToken
    at org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter.lambda$authenticate$6(AuthenticationWebFilter.java:123) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.authentication.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/login/oauth2/code/oauth?code=nTCRNi&state=Ub8jQjbp1baxhgsxcpNULMMHoV8z42bQsp62iL2jNV8%3D" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter.lambda$authenticate$6(AuthenticationWebFilter.java:123) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.4.12.jar:3.4.12]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400) ~[reactor-core-3.4.12.jar:3.4.12]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.4.12.jar:3.4.12]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxHide.java:147) ~[reactor-core-3.4.12.jar:3.4.12]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onComplete(MonoNext.java:102) ~[reactor-core-3.4.12.jar:3.4.12]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:367) ~[reactor-core-3.4.12.jar:3.4.12]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerComplete(FluxConcatMap.java:296) ~[reactor-core-3.4.12.jar:3.4.12]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onComplete(FluxConcatMap.java:885) ~[reactor-core-3.4.12.jar:3.4.12]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:196) ~[reactor-core-3.4.12.jar:3.4.12]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:268) ~[reactor-core-3.4.12.jar:3.4.12]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.4.12.jar:3.4.12]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:2058) ~[reactor-core-3.4.12.jar:3.4.12]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:2058) ~[reactor-core-3.4.12.jar:3.4.12]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.4.12.jar:3.4.12]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:196) ~[reactor-core-3.4.12.jar:3.4.12]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:268) ~[reactor-core-3.4.12.jar:3.4.12]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:2058) ~[reactor-core-3.4.12.jar:3.4.12]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onComplete(MonoNext.java:102) ~[reactor-core-3.4.12.jar:3.4.12]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.4.12.jar:3.4.12]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.4.12.jar:3.4.12]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260) ~[reactor-core-3.4.12.jar:3.4.12]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.4.12.jar:3.4.12]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:400) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.13.jar:1.0.13]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:419) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.13.jar:1.0.13]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:473) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.13.jar:1.0.13]
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:702) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.13.jar:1.0.13]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:93) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.13.jar:1.0.13]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103) ~[netty-codec-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[netty-transport-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324) ~[netty-codec-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296) ~[netty-codec-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[netty-transport-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719) ~[netty-transport-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655) ~[netty-transport-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581) ~[netty-transport-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986) ~[netty-common-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.70.Final.jar:4.1.70.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Dependency tree:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.2.0:tree (default-cli) @ springflux ---
[INFO] es._3xs.adp:springflux:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.32:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.14.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.14.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.32:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.29:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http:jar:1.0.13:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.70.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.70.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.70.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.70.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.70.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.70.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.70.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns:jar:4.1.70.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.70.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-dns:jar:4.1.70.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos:jar:osx-x86_64:4.1.70.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-classes-macos:jar:4.1.70.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.70.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.70.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-classes-epoll:jar:4.1.70.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-core:jar:1.0.13:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.70.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |           \- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.70.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webflux:jar:5.3.13:compile
[INFO] |     \- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.4.12:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:jar:1.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.68:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.68:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gateway-server:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.55:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |     +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |     |     +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |     \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- io.projectreactor.addons:reactor-extra:jar:3.4.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.6.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.13:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client:jar:5.6.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.6.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:5.6.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-core:jar:5.6.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.13:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.13:compile
[INFO]    \- com.nimbusds:oauth2-oidc-sdk:jar:9.19:compile
[INFO]       +- com.github.stephenc.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0-1:compile
[INFO]       +- com.nimbusds:content-type:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO]       +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.7:compile
[INFO]       |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.7:compile
[INFO]       |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.1:compile
[INFO]       +- com.nimbusds:lang-tag:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO]       \- com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:jar:9.14:compile
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------------------< es._3xs.adp:springflux >-----------------------
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: I think this has to do with the dependencies you are pulling in. The starters should pull in what you need, so why you are adding a lot of extra dependencies baffles me. Could you add the full output of the cmd `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: Yes of course, thank you very much for the answer, I edit the question adding this information.

Comment: Why do you have spring boot starter webflux and spring boot starter web added? If you want to run a webflux application you cant have both of them added

Comment: Sorry, it shouldn't be there, you're right. I put it there to test and rule out the error but I have removed it because the application won't start. However, the 500 error still appears with or without it.

Comment: please remove all unnecessary dependencies, it should be a minimal example

Comment: I've removed all unnecessary dependencies but I still get the same error. Nothing has changed. I have edited the question with the new dependencies.

Comment: Then you need to provide a small working example for us to look at.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was occurring because the default authentication manager wasn't working for me, I had to implement one specifically for my problem.

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
    @EnableWebFluxSecurity
    @EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
    public class WebFluxSecurityConfig {
    
        @Bean
        public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    
            return http
                    .httpBasic().disable()
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges
                            .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/oauth2/authorization/**",
                                    "/actuator",
                                    "/actuator/**",
                                    "/auth/login",
                                    "/login/**")
                            .permitAll()
                            .anyExchange()
                                    .authenticated()
                    .oauth2Login()
                    .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                    .and()
                    .build();
    
        }
}
```